# Managing Context Lifetime and IoC Container

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm working on an MVC style WinForms application, using Entity Framework and using Unity to inject a `DbContext` into my `Repository` objects.  I'm having trouble deciding how to manage my `DbContext` lifetime, while handling my IoC container's scope and lifetime correctly too.

Each form has a controller behind it.  Each controller gets its service dependencies injected.  Each service gets its repository injected as a dependency.  Each repository gets a `DbContext` injected.

For instance, if I have a form where the user can enter an order, the code structure looks like this

```
public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
{
   private readonly MyContext context;
   public OrderRepository(MyContext context)
   {
      this.context = context;
   }
}

public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
   private readonly IOrderRepository orderRepository;
   public OrderService(IOrderRepository orderRepository)
   {
      this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
   }
}

public class OrderController
{
   private readonly IOrderService orderService;
   public OrderController(IOrderService orderService)
   {
      this.orderService = orderService;
   }
}
```

The general recommendation for Entity Framework with WinForms seems to be to create one `DbContext` per form.  In addition, one of my controllers has a timer which fires asynchronous tasks at scheduled times, and I want each task to use a separate `DbContext`.

In order to create a new `OrderService`, `OrderRepository`, and `MyContext` for each new form and its controller (and for each asynchronous task within one of the controllers), I'll have to either create a new `UnityContainer` each time a new form is opened and each time an async task is created, or I'll have to store my `UnityContainer` globally.  Is it OK to store the `UnityContainer` globally, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Inject a factory instead of concrete instance. Then use factory to create as many services\repositories\whatever as you need. It's generally considered not a good practice to use container globally (so called service location (anti)pattern).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: In most containers you can just inject Func<SomeInterface> but not sure if Unity also allows this, I usually use other containers.